# Что лучше enum или константы в классе

Tags: java

Что лучше `enum`

```
enum type {
   Int, Long, String, Boolean, Unknown
}
```

Или `class`

```
public final class type {
 public final static byte Int = 0;
 public final static byte Long = 1;
 public final static byte String = 2;
 public final static byte Boolean = 3;
 public final static byte Unknown = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`enum`'ы надо использовать для какого-то диапазона:

```
public enum Color{
    White,
    Red,
    Blue
}
```

Константы для чего-то уникального, к примеру

```
class Math{
    public float PI = 3.14f;
}
```

Плюсы `enum`'ов?

`enum` - это тип, так что можно так делать:

```
enum Color { Red,Green,Blue };
enum Size { Big,Little };

void f( Color c ) {
}

void f( Size s ) {
}

int main() {
    f( Red );
    f( Big );
}
```

С константами не получится.

Главное, как мне кажется, `enum`'ы - безопасны.

Для `enum`'а вы указываете сигнатуру явно задавая тип:

```
void f( Color c ){}
```

Вы туда ничего другого кроме этого enum'а передать не сможете, иначе ругаться будет на уровне компилятора, вы даже собрать проект не сможете.

Для констант было бы так:

```
void f( int c ){}
```

Если вы в этот метод передадите не ту константу, то ошибку заметите только в рантайме.

**UPD**: про память.

Если у вас, к примеру, есть enum:

```
public enum Color{
        White,
        Red,
        Blue
    }
```

Скомпилируем этот `enum` задизасемблим полученный файл с помощью **javap**, получим что-то такое:

```
Скомпилирован из "Color.java"
public final class Color extends java.lang.Enum{
    public static final Color White;
    public static final Color Red;
    public static final Color Blue;
    public static Color [] values();
    public static Color valueOf(java.lang.String);
    static {};
}
```

Так что да, какой-то оверхед по памяти будет.

Comment: Хорошо, а как с памятью? Ведь мне кажется туда попадут ссылки на обьект, а константы только значения?

Comment: А еще enum умеет хорошо в [синглтоны](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129494/)

Comment: Ок, спасибо   разобрался

Comment: @ДенисКотляров про память дописал в ответе

Comment: @ДенисКотляров не стоит беспокоиться о памяти на таком уровне. 20-30 байт памяти сильно меньше стоят чем правильность и поддерживаемость кода.

Comment: Хе, интересно, спасибо за подробные сведенья)

Comment: @DmitryV. зря вы так. В первых версиях Android по-этому и использовались константы для всего, а не `enum`'ы. Правда, там Dalvik, и от этого часть проблем...

Comment: В андроиде все как-то облегчено, например пишут используйте место ArrayList другой класс от андроида, не знаю что за класс. Или не например используйте прямые ссылки на int, а не с помощью функций получения тогоже int и многое другое.

Comment: @Suvitruf не отрицаю, но это специфика платформы, для которой есть специальный [@IntDef](https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-ii-bb9a51f8c8b9#.s2yz1tw6v) костыль.

Comment: Если же речь в вопросе идет о полноценной java на сервере, то в 99% случаев enum будет лучше.

Comment: Ага, я не против андроида, платформа в целом нравится, но есть один минус, так это студия) Просто в моем компе с этой студией не поработаешь.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров пока ещё можно в Eclipse )

Comment: Да) но в студии есть хороший граф редактор, но думаю в скоре он мне совсем не понадобится.