# Enum и константы в чем отличие?

Tags: java

Старый способ имитации "перечисления":

```
public static final int TOM = 1;
public static final int JERRY = 1;
public static final int REX = 1;
```

Новое, перечисление:

```
public enum Names {
BOBBY, BILLY, SOFFIE
}
```

Так в чем отличие? Зачем сделали перечисления "Enum"?

Comment: Почитайте ответы в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468120/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-enum-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5). Проще говоря отличие заключается в том что константы - это примитивы, а enum - классы, на которых можно применить switch. в enum можно добавить поля и методы.

Comment: например, чтоб не вышло, что `(TOM == JERRY) == true`.. Так то, дополнительное место для выстрела себе в ногу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Описание `enum` -- это, по сути дела, описание класса и одновременно фиксированного набора именованных объектов этого класса. Объекты этого класса могут обладать всеми атрибутами обычных объектов -- конструкторами, полями, методами. Конструкторы могут инициализировать внутренние состояния этих объектов, поля -- хранить их состояния, в том числе ссылки на какие-то более/менее сложные объекты, методы могут реализовать какую-то функциональность.

Так что перечисление -- это не просто набор значений, которые можно использовать в операторе `switch`, их возможности намного больше.

С помощью перечислений можно, например, описать набор команд GUI -- каждая команда может иметь состояние (разрешено/запрещено), текст, отображаемый в меню и зависящий от состояния, текст всплывающей подсказки, ссылку на объект, который выполняет команду и т. п. Другой пример -- описание колонок таблицы, с информацией о ширине колонки, о том, как форматировать данные в этой колонке и проч., или параметры, определяющие режим работы приложения.

Да вообще много разных применений может быть, во многих случаях, когда количество разных объектов какого-то типа известно заранее. Грамотное использование перечислений может сильно улучшить дизайн приложения. Так что использование их просто в качестве именованных констант -- далеко не главное их применение. Вот навскидку пример того, что можно делать с перечислениями:

```
    public class Test_enums_2 {

        static class EnumData {
            int intValue;
            String stringValue;

            EnumData(int intValue, String stringValue) {
                this.intValue = intValue; 
                this.stringValue = stringValue;
            }

            void setNewString(String s) { this.stringValue = s; }
            public String toString()    { return intValue + ": " + stringValue; }
            int calcSomething()         { return intValue * stringValue.length(); }
            // Anything else...
        }

        enum EnumExample {
            ENUM1_ITEM1(1, "Раз"),
            ENUM1_ITEM2(2, "Два"),
            ENUM1_ITEM3(3, "Три"),
            ENUM1_ITEM4(4, "Четыре");

            private EnumData data;
            private boolean enabled = true;

            EnumExample(int intValue, String stringValue) {
                data = new EnumData(intValue, stringValue);
            }

            public void setEnabled(boolean newValue) {
                enabled = newValue;
            }

            public void setString(String newValue) {
                data.stringValue = newValue;
            }

            public String getFullName() {
                if (!enabled)   return "Ничего не скажу. Запрещено";
                else            return data.toString(); 
            }

            public String getShortName() {
                return String.valueOf(data.intValue);
            }

            public int calculate() {
                return data.calcSomething();
            } 
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EnumExample.ENUM1_ITEM3.setEnabled(false);
            for (EnumExample item: EnumExample.values()) {
                System.out.format("%s: Short name: %s, full name: %s, calc: %s\n", 
                                    item, item.getShortName(), 
                                    item.getFullName(), item.calculate());
            }

            System.out.println();
            EnumExample.ENUM1_ITEM1.setString("Ку-ку");
            EnumExample.ENUM1_ITEM2.setEnabled(false);
            EnumExample.ENUM1_ITEM3.setEnabled(true);

            for (EnumExample item: EnumExample.values()) {
                System.out.format("%s: Short name: %s, full name: %s, calc: %s\n", 
                                    item, item.getShortName(), 
                                    item.getFullName(), item.calculate());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ну и в отладчике видно не число-константу а сразу имя